# play/pause = background fadetoggle. end of video = background fadein

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, fade

I took some code off the internet.
http://www.creativebloq.com/html5/build-custom-html5-video-player-9134473
All the code is downloadable or you can see it on this page.

In a JavaScript file, there they put the video structure within a function. All the buttons for the player are listed in div class and span within a function in the JavaScript file. Not the html.

So she I tried to do the fadetoggle on the play/pause button I referred to the button class in the JavaScript file. And I wrote the fade free function in html. It doesn't pick up the button class or any other element from javafile. The function only picks up elements from html file.

The function works. If a use class container from html which holds all the video in it, it works.but I only need the play button.

So essentially, can a class listed in Java file NOT IN HTML, example:' ' be used in the fadetoggle function?

Comment: Ok maybe I wrote just a bunch of confusing text. I'll try to post it again differently. Thank you

Comment: (**Not in HTML**)? you do know that div and span are html elements... Do you understand any of this source code you're using? If you want to change the way your buttons act when clicked you should look for the `mediaPlayer.addEventListener` for  play/pause Or `togglePlayPause()`. If you don't understand the source code I recommend you research on javascript, this will help you understand how to add/edit the existing source code.

Comment: Yes. I know. Well not that I know code. I just understood that from some tutorials. And sorry about the link in my post. It's the wrong one. In the mean time I found the solution.

Comment: all the structure of the video player was built as a plug-in in java. no html present for the structure of the video. It's still is confusing to me but at list I found the class to link my fadetoggle function to (it is still in java file, not in html). Thank you NewToJS for advice

Answer (score 0):

This is from their website (http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/03/custom-html5-video-player/). The website I took the code off of. All these classes in java. But I found the class to help me link the play/pause button. It was still in the java file, some other place, not in the structure of the video. I still don;t know why I can't link a function to those in the structure video.

```
       // Wrap the video in a div with the class of your choosing
            $this.wrap('<div class="'+$settings.videoClass+'"></div>');


            // Select the div we just wrapped our video in for easy selection.
            var $that = $this.parent('.'+$settings.videoClass);

// The Structure of our video player
             {

  $( '<div class="player">'
 + '<div class="play-pause play">'
   + '<span class="play-button">&#9658;</span>'
   + '<div class="pause-button">'
     + '<span> </span>'
         + '<span> </span>'
   + '</div>'
 + '</div>'
 + '<div class="progress">'
   + '<div class="progress-bar">'
     + '<div class="button-holder">'
       + '<div class="progress-button"> </div>'
     + '</div>'
   + '</div>'
   + '<div class="time">'
     + '<span class="ctime">00:00</span>'
     + '<span class="stime"> / </span>'
     + '<span class="ttime">00:00</span>'
   + '</div>'
 + '</div>'
 + '<div class="volume">'
   + '<div class="volume-holder">'
     + '<div class="volume-bar-holder">'
       + '<div class="volume-bar">'
         + '<div class="volume-button-holder">'  
           + '<div class="volume-button"> </div>'
         + '</div>'
       + '</div>'
     + '</div>'
   + '</div>'
   + '<div class="volume-icon v-change-0">'
     + '<span> </span>'
   + '</div>'
 + '</div>'
 + '<div class="fullscreen"> '
   + '<a href="#"> </a>'
 + '</div>'
```

+ '') .appendTo($that);

}